# Как переводится китайское слово "大叔"?

Tags: переводы

- В словаре:

大叔[1]
dàshū

1) вежл. дядя; Вы (к другу отца, мужчине одного поколения или возраста с отцом)

2) жарг. взрослый мужчина (30-35 лет)
大叔控 девушка, предпочитающая мужчин постарше

- В разговорной речи китайского языка:

А если на китайском языке, 大叔 имеет оттенки в значении слова. Речь идёт **о зрелом мужчине, который является кем-то, кто понравился молодой девушке.**

В данной ситуации, *как переводится китайское слово "大叔" на русском?*

[1] взята цитата из словаря 大БКРС.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если контекст требует такого перевода (в простейшем смысле это просто "дядя"), то в русском есть такой жаргонизм, как "**папик**"; словари синонимов трактуют его как "*богатый немолодой любовник*".

Статья на эту тему:

https://lady.tut.by/news/relationship/340059.html